# Separating Duplicate Rows into Separate Columns TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a block of data which has duplicate row ID's (CLIENT_DIWOR is the ROW ID) but relate to different groups. I can't just delete the duplicate row as they tie in to two different groups, so what I am trying to do is move the duplicate to the next column, so I can get the calculations correct at the end of my query. So for an example of what I am after

This is what I have

```
    CLIENT_DIWOR    GROUP_NAME
        -1          Priv Client Serv (Sector)
        -1          Social Business (Sector)
```

This is what I want

```
CLIENT_DIWOR    GROUP_NAME                    Second Group Name
     -1         Priv Client Serv (Sector)   Social Business (Sector)
```

I have tried using COUNT(*) with a group by but that doesn't bring the correct results as it will just tell me there are 1 of everything, and what I am after is every time client_DIWOR duplicates add 1 to the previous number, as that will give me what I need to separate them out and rebuild it into a table, but I just cant see how to count it without grouping the numbers together, this is what I have so far with the count removed as I know that is wrong.

```
SELECT A.CLIENT_DIWOR,B.GROUP_NAME
from CLIENT_GRP_MEMBER A 
JOIN CLIENT_GROUP B on B.DIWOR = A.CLIENT_GRP_DIWOR
order by CLIENT_DIWOR
```

Comment: Nothing in your query or data is called "row id", which makes your question very hard to follow.

Comment: CLIENT_DIWOR is the Row Id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more general solution, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.CLIENT_DIWOR ORDER BY B.GROUP_NAME) rn
    FROM CLIENT_GRP_MEMBER A 
    INNER JOIN CLIENT_GROUP B
        ON B.DIWOR = A.CLIENT_GRP_DIWOR
)

SELECT
    CLIENT_DIWOR,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN GROUP_NAME END) AS GROUP_NAME,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN GROUP_NAME END) AS SECOND_GROUP_NAME
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    CLIENT_DIWOR;
```

The advantage of this approach is that you ever need to cater to more than two columns in the output, you can easily extend the query.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I am after. Especially as there are some that appear 4 times

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put two groups for each `CLIENT_DIWOR`, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT CLIENT_DIWOR,
       MIN(GROUP_NAME) as GROUP_NAME
       NULLIF(MAX(GROUP_NAME), MIN(GROUP_NAME)) as GROUP_NAME_2
from CLIENT_GRP_MEMBER cgm
GROUP BY CLIENT_DIWOR ;
```